# Algorithm to produce rounded edges and corners in a 3D mesh

Tags: algorithm, 3d, rounded-corners, mesh

Starting with a 3D mesh, how would you give a rounded appearance to the edges and corners between the polygons of that mesh?

---

Without wishing to discourage other approaches, here's how I'm currently approaching the problem:

Given the mesh for a regular polyhedron, I can give the mesh's edges a rounded appearance by scaling each polygon along its plane and connecting the edges using cylinder segments such that each cylinder is tangent to each polygon where it meets that polygon.

Here's an example involving a cube:

[image: Cube]

Here's the cube after scaling its polygons:

[image: Cube after scaling polygons]

Here's the cube after connecting the polygons' edges using cylinders:

[image: Cube with rounded edges]

What I'm having trouble with is figuring out how to deal with the corners between polygons, especially in cases where more than three edges meet at each corner. I'd also like an algorithm that works for all closed polyhedra instead of just those that are regular.

Comment: What do you know about those meshes? With your strategy it's unclear how to handle special cases such as sattle points. Also what should happen with very small geometry (smaller than the radius) should it vanish? Do you plan to use a fixed radius?

Comment: Saddle points would be joined by a flat surface (essentially, a sphere of infinite radius). As for very small geometry, the method I describe above does not take radius as an input; instead, connected polygons are scaled along their planes to create a gap between the edges and the radius is whatever is needed to smoothly join the now separated edges of these previously connected polygons.

Comment: I don't get how to connect round edges with a flat surface, but I guess thats part of the question:-) An other thing, how do you intend to deal with the self-intersections that can result from such a transformation (think of the edge between to large polygons with small geometry right below it)?

Comment: @Lawnmower: It seems to me the proper way to connect two polygons at a saddle point (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SaddlePoint.html) is to use a flat polygon. Why? Because the derivative at a saddle point is 0, so the slope of the tangent at that point is also 0 and therefore the connecting polygon should be flat. As for self-intersections, I'm not quite sure what you mean. If the edge between the polygons lies above the small geometry, how can scaling them in place and adding a cylinder segment produce an intersection? Rounding the edges is equivalent to removing mass, not adding it.

Answer (score 2):

I post this as an answer because I can't put images into comments.

**Sattle point**

Here's an image of two brothers camping:

[image: sattlepoint]

They placed their simple tents right beside each other in the middle of a steep walley (that's one bad place for tents, but thats not the point), so one end of each tent points upwards. At the point where the four squares meet you have a sattle point. The two edges on top of each tent can be rounded normally as well as the two downward edges. But at the sattle point you have different curvature in both directions and therefore its not possible to use a sphere. This rules out Svante's solution.

**Selfintersection**

The following image shows some 3D polygons if viewed from the side. Its some sharp thing with a hole drilled into it from the other side. The left image shows it before, the right after rounding.

[image]
.

The mass thats get removed from the sharp edge containts the end of the drill hole.

There is someething else to see here. The drill holes sides might be very large polygons (lets say it's not a hole but a slit). Still you only get small radii at the top. you can't just scale your polygons, you have to take into account the neighboring polygon.

**Convexity**

You say you're only removing mass, this is only true if your geometry is convex. Look at the image you posted. But now assume that the viewer is *inside* the volume. The radii turn away from you and therefore add mass.

**NURBS**

I'm not a nurbs specialist my self. But the constraints would look something like this:
The corners of the nurbs patch must be at the same position as the corners of the scaled-down polygons. The normal vectors of the nurb surface at the corners must be equal to the normal of the polygon. This should be sufficent to gurarantee that the nurb edge will be a straight line following the polygon edge. The normals also ensure that no visible edges will result at the border between polygon and nurbs patch.

I'd just do the math myself. nurbs are just polygons. You'll have some unknown coefficients and your constraints. This gives you a system of equations (often linear) that you can solve.

Comment: (1) I thought by "sattle point" you meant something else, but it's basically what I was thinking of when I said to Svante that spheres wouldn't work when not all polygons that meet have the same angle between them, as in the image you've presented. (2) I see now what you meant by self-intersections. For some reason I was thinking of the large polygons being angled in the opposite direction as in your image. I don't know how to address it except by rounding the small geometry more aggressively or the large polygons less aggressively. It's not likely to become an issue for my purposes.

Comment: (3) I see now how a convex polygon would gain mass at edges where it's convex. (4) I'll have to think some more about the NURBS approach before I comment on it.

Comment: regarding (3): mass is lost at convex edges and gained at concave ones.

Comment: @Lawnmower: Doh. I got convex and concave mixed up.

Comment: @Lawnmower: On the matter of NURBS patches, can the polygons that make up the cage of a NURBS surface be something other than quads? I don't know how to connect the various corners of the scaled-down polygons using only quads. For instance, the cube in my mockup has three polygon corners meeting at each of the cube's corners, while more complex shapes could involve more than four.

Comment: afaik this should be possible. quads are the just easiest, most common case. I'd dig into the nurbs math, you'll have to anyway. I'd guess that in the end you'll end up using a trianglar (or what ever) subarea of the (u,v) parameter space.

Comment: It now occurs to me that I can turn any convex polygon into a group of quads by adding a central point and connecting the midpoint of each edge to this central point. I could then attach these to quads that make up the rounded edges and treat the whole thing like a NURBS surface. I just don't know if there's likely to be any smoothness problems with such an arrangement of quads for the NURBS control cage.

Comment: "midpoint of each edge to this central point" wouldn't this produce triangles? For quads you'd have to use two 'original' edges plus the two that you get by connecting to the central vertex. This opens the question of what do to if you face an odd number of edges..

Comment: In order to get triangles you'd have to connect the central point to each of the polygon's vertices. When you connect the central point to the midpoints of the polygon's edges, you get quads instead: half of two contiguous edges plus lines from the midpoints of those edges to the central point makes four edges and therefore a quad.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any upper bound on the number of faces, that meet at that corner?

You might you might employ concepts from CAGD, especially Non-Uniform Rational B-Splines (NURBS) might be of interest for you.

Your current approach - glueing some fixed geometrical primitives might be too inflexible to solve the problem. NURBS require some mathematical work to get used to, but might be more suitable for your needs.

Comment: I'd rather have a general-purpose algorithm, but for my current purposes the maximum number of faces around a corner vertex is 5. Also, you may assume the mesh is always closed. 

I don't know much about NURBS surfaces, but even with NURBS it seems to me the problem remains of how to blend the various rounded edges that meet at the corner.

Comment: NURBS seem to be a good idea. They can handle all the special cases and offer great flexibility. Since they're based on polynomials they cannot form perfect circular forms like cylinders. But they approximate them very well. Basically what you do is, you set contraints at the boundaries of the NURBS patch, like that it should connect to the shrunk polygons and to neighboring NURBS and then let the 'math' fill the surface smoothly.

Comment: I'm not able to visualize it, perhaps due to my relative lack of experience with NURBS. How would the control points be arranged? What would be their weights?

Comment: In section 8.7 of Piegl and Tiller's "The NURBS Book", the authors discuss the creation of rounded edges and corners (also known fillet surfaces) for the case where 3 edges meet at a vertex. For corner fillets in general, however, the authors go on to say the situation "is more complex", and that a corner patch "may not even be representable as a NURBS surface."

Answer (score 1):

Extrapolating your cylinder-edge approach, the corners should be spheres, resp. sphere segments, that have the same radius as the cylinders meeting there and the centre at the intersection of the cylinders' axes.

Comment: Spheres would work when all the incoming edges have curves with the same radius, but what about when the incoming curved edges have different radii (as when not all the faces that meet have the same angle between them)? How would you blend them in that case?

Comment: @Adrian Lopez: I would not use different radii for the cylinders.  You can accomodate different angles between adjacent faces by just changing the segment angle.

Comment: @Svante: What do you mean "changing the segment angle"?

Comment: @Adrian Lopez: You can accomodate all possible angles with a single radius.  Visualize the faces as tangential planes to the cylinder.  The planar angle is the same as the angle of the visible segment of the cylinder, independent of the radius.

Comment: @Svante: For a single radius to connect the edges of two polygons, the cylinder's position would have to be shifted up or down depending on the angle between polygons being less or more acute, respectively, which seems to me would make blending the edges at a corner even more difficult. Also, it may lead to situations where the cylinder would be located so far away from the edge that it would lie outside the opposite ends of the polygons themselves. Finally, I would need a different approach to creating the initial gaps between polygons than my current method of shrinking them all in place.

Comment: @Adrian Lopez:  Of course, you need to choose a radius that does not "eat" a face completely.  I think that the easiest approach is to construct an "inner polygon" which is defined by having all faces at a fixed distance equal to the radius to the corresponding outer face.  These faces are then translated out by the radius, the edges used as axes for cylinders of the radius, and the corners as centres for spheres of the radius.

Comment: @Svante that's the way, but it will only work for convex geometry. Also small geometry will cause all sorts of problems. This is how it would work for convex geometry: for each surface of the polyhedron (the polygons), create the corresponding plane. Translate each plane torwards the inside by r. Treat each plane as an inequality. The points satisfying all inequalities make the "inner polyhedron" you where talking about. The way with the inequalities ensures that small geometry is handled properly (that is, it vanishes).

Answer (score 1):

Here we have a single C++ header for generating triangulated rounded 3D boxes. The code is in C++ but also easy to transplant to other coding languages. Also it's easy to be modified for other primitives like quads.

https://github.com/nepluno/RoundCornerBox

Answer (score 0):

As @Raymond suggests, I also think that the [nepluno repo](https://github.com/nepluno/RoundCornerBox) provides a very good implementation to solve this issue; efficient and simple.

To complete his answer, I just wrote a solution to this issue in JS, based on the BabylonJS 3D engine. This solution can be found here, and can be quite easily replaced by another 3D engine:

https://playground.babylonjs.com/#AY7B23